# Favorite Web Form Validation Technique

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, validation, sanitization

What is everyone's favorite way to sanitize user data?

I've been using Javascript, but have recently required something more secure (people can turn it off, after all), so I was looking at Flex, but thought I'd ask the community what they thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NEVER NEVER NEVER use javascript **or any other client-side technology** for the *only* validation.  You can use client-side validation to save some load on your server or make your app seem more responsive by showing the error sooner when validation fails, but you should **always** validate using server-side code.

Personally, I like the ASP.Net validation controls because it gives you the benefit of client-side validation with security of server-side, without having to write your logic twice.  Of course, the stock controls are pretty bare, but you can extend them.

Answer (score 3):

Validation should ALWAYS be done server-side. Doing it client-side, in addition, is fine.

How you do it depends on what your app is written in. Any language should be able to handle validation; the logic used is what matters, not the language.

It also depends on what you're doing with the data you're given. Putting it in a URL or storing it in a SQL database requires two very different kinds of sanitization. If at all possible, white-list valid values--don't black-list invalid values. Someone will always be able to come up with a new mal-input you hadn't considered.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the requirements of your project you may or may not want to implement client-side validation. However, server-side validation should ALWAYS be implemented. I prefer to white-list appropriate inputs and values as opposed to black-listing invalid data because this ensures that no one will ever slip something by that I failed to consider.

Answer (score 1):

- always use server side validation at the very least
- use regular expressions

PHP Example:

```
preg_match('/^[\w][\w\,\-\.]*\@[\w]+[\w\-\.]*$/', $_GET['email'], $matches);
if (count($matches) > 0) {
  $_GET['email'] = $matches[0];
} else {
  die('invalid email address');
}
```

Comment: But rfc 2821 denotes that never ever must anyone else that the host-server validate anything in the username-part, e.g. @anyhost.com is a valid smtp-address !-)

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use both server- and client-side validation.
I use JQuery for client side validation.